# Any way to faster sql query containing IN clause where data for IN clause is obtained from with in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

During my project, I came across a requirement where I need to process some operation over some address which is not present inside some other table, and for that, I have written the following query. But I think this query will go slow when the entries in the second table 'transaction' increases.

```
select emp_address
from emp_leave_wallet
where attached  ="mycompany_wallet" and
      emp_address not in (select destination_address from transaction);
```

Any other way, other than adding Index over destination_address.

Comment: I think right or left join is the better alternative. But it is hard to say without knowing your table stuctrue

Comment: Your query is fine. It can be re-written with `NOT EXISTS` or an anti join. However, the optimizer should know this too, and get to the same execution plan for all three queries. If `destination_address` is nullable however, you must be careful with `NOT IN`, as this will not return any row, if there is a null entry in `transaction` (because null is supposed to be an unknown value, so the DBMS cannot honestly tell you the `emp_address` is not in the set, or so they argue ;-)

Comment: Also MySQL tends to optimize worse with a large number of records going into the `IN` or `NOT IN` operators @ThorstenKettner so this query is likely a good candidate to be rewritten into a `LEFT JOIN` instead

Answer (score 2):

A solution using a `JOIN` but I can't quantify the performance gain:

```
SELECT ew.emp_address
FROM emp_leave_wallet ew
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction t on
    t.emp_address = ew.emp_address
WHERE ew.attached = "mycompany_wallet" and
      t.emp_address IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with `not exists`:

```
select lw.emp_address
from emp_leave_wallet lw
where lw.attached  = 'mycompany_wallet' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from destination_address da
                  where lw.emp_address = da.destination_address 
                 );
```

Then for this query you definitely want an index on `destination_address(destination_address)` and probably on `(attached, emp_address)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`  :

```
select ew.emp_addres
from emp_leave_wallet ew
where ew.attached = "mycompany_wallet" and
      not exists (select 1 from transaction t where t.destination_address = ew.emp_address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` which returns record if there is no matching row in `transaction` table based on `where` condition:

```
select emp_address
from emp_leave_wallet e
where attached = 'mycompany_wallter'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from transaction t
    where e.emp_address = t.destination_address
    )
```

Create indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON emp_leave_wallet(attached, emp_address);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON transaction(destination_address);
```

Comment: How not exists will save the day and will be able to make query even faster, could you please explain. thank you.

Comment: Google: NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS. Many resources there. An example on SO would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists Another blog: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_address
from emp_leave_wallet
where attached  ="mycompany_wallet" and
      emp_address not in (select destination_address from transaction);
```

Your `emp_leave_wallet` and `transaction` table should have id fields (I'm guessing ... `emp_id`, `transaction_id`)

If it were me i would...

```
select emp_address
from emp_leave_wallet elw
inner join transaction t
on elw.emp_id = t.transacation_id
```